# Centering Flex Boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have code below for multiple flex boxes. How would I center them vertically in the page when the page is being expanded? I tried using `justify-content: center;` in my `flex-container` but it does work when I'm using `flex: 1 0 auto;` to make the boxes responsive. Anything helps, thanks.

```css
.flex-container {
    display:flex;}

.flex-post { 
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height:auto;
    max-height:270px;
    max-width:270px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display:flex;}

.flex-post:before {
    content:'';
    float:left;
    padding-top:100%;}

.flex-post:hover { 
    background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.5);}
```

```html
<div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-post">1</div>
    <div class="flex-post">2</div>
    <div class="flex-post">3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-post">4</div>
    <div class="flex-post">5</div>
    <div class="flex-post">6</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-post">7</div>
    <div class="flex-post">8</div>
    <div class="flex-post">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-start {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-end {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Now with those classes, you can do things like this:

**Horizontally center:**

```
<div class="flex flex-row flex-center">foo</div>
```

**Vertically center:**

```
<div class="flex flex-column flex-center full-height">foo</div>
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dxy2ag5c/2/ - Just wrap your original HTML in a div using my "vertically center" classes, and it takes the whole 3x3 grid and vertically centers it.

Comment: Your right it does work, but I was trying it on IE 11 and apparently it doesn't on there, thanks!